# Upload file using Jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to upload file using jquery from my modal popup.
But I get the `HttpPostedFileBase` as null during ajax call.
Can anyone help me out on this. Below is the jquery code:

```
function uploadDocument(contactId, tripId, file) {
if ($('#documentUploadInput').val() == '') {
    alertify.error('Please select a file to upload');
    return;
}
$.ajax({
    url: '/CRMDomain/ContactDetail/UploadDocument',
    data: { contactId: contactId, tripId: tripId, file: file },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function () {
        alertify.success('Uploaded');
        $('#CRMUploadDocumentModal').modal('hide');
    },
    error: function () {
        alertify.error('Not Uploaded');
    }
});
```

}

And this is the way i call the jquery function:

```
<input id="btnSave" 
       type="button" 
       value="Upload" 
       class="btn btn-default"  onclick='uploadDocument($("#ContactId").val(), $("#tripId").val(), $("#documentUploadInput")[0].files[0]);' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't post file so easy with Ajax.

The best solution that I always use is to use [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) then you should just change your `.ajax` to `.ajaxForm`.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960245/1849444) for more details.

Comment: @AnabikThakur no problem. I prefer it over `FormData()` becouse of IE 8 compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You've to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to send the multipart file format to the controller action.

Try the following ajax query to post the file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/CRMDomain/ContactDetail/UploadDocument',
    data: { contactId: contactId, tripId: tripId, file: new FormData($("#documentUploadInput")[0].files[0]) },
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function () {
        alertify.success('Uploaded');
        $('#CRMUploadDocumentModal').modal('hide');
    },
    error: function () {
        alertify.error('Not Uploaded');
    }
});
```

You've to manually set `processData: false`, otherwise jQuery would convert your file to a string. And you also need to set `contentType: false` as jQuery would override you content type when submitting the request.

post your controller action in the question as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used ajaxForm to accomplish it. I will use this code later to see if this also works. It might help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
  var fileUpload = $("#documentUploadInput").get(0);//Upload input box
  var file = fileUpload.files;
  var data= new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  data.append('file', file[i]);
}
  data.contactId = $("#ContactId").val();
  data.tripId= $("#tripId").val();
$.ajax({
  url: "/CRMDomain/ContactDetail/UploadDocument",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  data: data,
  success: function (result) {
     alert(result);
},
error: function (err) {
    alert(err.statusText);
 }
  });
 });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change little bit code.

```
var files = $('#documentUploadInput').get(0).files;
var data = new FormData();
if (files.length > 0) {
    data.append('file', files[0]);
}

$.ajax({
        url: '/CRMDomain/ContactDetail/UploadDocument',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data ,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        error: function errorAlert(e, errorMsg) {
            alert("Your request was not successful: " + errorMsg);
       }
    });
```